# DOMDocument and content intended for web browsers

Tags: php, xhtml, domdocument

Since `DOMDocument` does not support XHTML output, shout it be avoided as a means to render content intended for web browsers? If this is the case, what alternatives are out there (that hopefully come natively distributed with php) that allow convenient DOM manipulation and XHTML output?

Comment: @jycr753: I'll have a look, thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

For best HTML/XHTML manipulation which is integrated easily with PHP, then you can give a try on this
[Simple DOM HTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)